# A before_filter for Omniauth Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth

For devise there is a very easy to use Before_filter to use in the controllers.

For some reason I can't get this to work for the Omniauth_facebook Gem. I followed the Railscast on Facebook Omniauth and also

```
 before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
   redirect_to :login unless User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])
 end
 end
```

but I get an error:

```
   NameError in PostsController#new

    undefined local variable or method `auth' for #<PostsController:0x007f9fbfa7ee58>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the variable named auth. So you need to check that auth variable initialized somewhere or not. As per my view, OmniAuth Facebook gem is storing the authenticated data in request env. Please refer this: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash.

before_filter will execute before serving the request. so may be that causes the issues.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the auth variable you're after is request.env["omniauth.auth"]

Comment: Just tried:def authenticate
   redirect_to :login unless User.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth.auth["provider"], omniauth.auth["uid"]), but get the same only undefined local variable or method `omniauth' for #<PostsController:0x007f9fbf6d29d0