# How to add a before filter for Facebook Omniauth Railscast?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth

I followed the Omniauth Facebook Railscast and everything works fine.

Now I want to add a before filter, but can't manage to find an easy way to make it work?

I tried, but get an error. I tried [OmniAuth before_filter for requiring login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477745/omniauth-before-filter-for-requiring-login) also no luck.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code of what you tried or at least something so we can try to help?

Comment: You can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677247/a-before-filter-for-omniauth-facebook/16677565?noredirect=1#16677565

Comment: I wasn't getting anywhere, replies and help included so I rephrased and posted the question.